# expect auto login sucess, but can't exec any command

Tags: linux, bash, expect

the shell code:

**~  cat test_longin.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 120
spawn /usr/bin/ssh fuyou@target.server
expect "*assword*"
send "fuyou\n"
interact
```

When I type `./test_login.sh`, it can login target servers successfully, but when I execute `ls` command, the console doesn't output any text. So I can't exec any commond on target server. Is the interaction problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should expect something after send, but not use command "interact" immediately.

```
xxx:/home/username/temp # cat t1.exp 
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh serverx

expect "#"
send "ls -l\r"
expect "#"
interact
```